Why wouldn't the result display in the browser?
Using alert() in the switch statement works but why wouldn't it display the result in the browser using the below code?


do {
  let playerMove = prompt('Please enter your move', 'e.g rock, paper or scissors');
  let computerMove = ['rock', 'paper', 'scissors'];

  switch (playerMove) {
    case 'rock':
      document.querySelector('p').innerHTML = computerMove[Math.floor(Math.random() * 3)] + ' vs  your rock';
      break;
    case 'paper':
      document.querySelector('p').innerHTML = computerMove[Math.floor(Math.random() * 3)] + ' vs your paper';
      break;
    case 'scissors':
      document.querySelector('p').innerHTML = computerMove[Math.floor(Math.random() * 3)] + ' vs your scissors';
      break;
    default:
      document.querySelector('p').innerHTML = 'You need to learn how to play Rock, Paper, Scissors';
  }
} while (confirm('Wanna play again?'))
<h2>Rock Paper Scissors</h2>
<p></p>




Javascript is single-threaded (in the browser).  That thread is also used to update the UI.  Your thread is busy.

The issue is because JS is single-threaded. Therefore that thread is still stuck in your while loop and cannot repaint the UI. The alert() temporarily stops this loop and allows a repaint.
The best way to improve this would be to remove the while loop and instead place your logic in a function which recursively calls itself if the player wants to continue on with another game.
Also note that you can DRY up the logic by concatenating the player's choice to the output string instead of using a switch to handle each case individually:


const playGame = () => {
  const label = document.querySelector('p');
  const moves = ['rock', 'paper', 'scissors'];
  
  const playerMove = prompt('Please enter your move', 'e.g rock, paper or scissors');
  const computerMove = moves[Math.floor(Math.random() * 3)];

  let labelText = 'You need to learn how to play Rock, Paper, Scissors';
  if (moves.includes(playerMove)) {
    labelText = `${computerMove} vs your ${playerMove}`;
  }

  label.textContent = labelText;

  // in a timeout to allow the UI to update before the modal popup is shown
  setTimeout(() => {
    if (confirm('Wanna play again?'))
      playGame();
  }, 0);
}

playGame();
<h2>Rock Paper Scissors</h2>
<p></p>




FYI: recursive calls will (eventually) hit a stack overflow.  You'd have to play a lot of games, so an ok solution until that point, but worth being aware of.  See browser stack size (slightly outdated).   The solution is to put it in a setTimeout (which the edit now does...)

True, I was going to put a note about that, but if you play 20,000 games in a row you deserve your browser crash XD

@fdomn-m just curious, how could we use  setTimeout  here? Wouldn't we have to create a function anyways?

@donniedarko the example in my answer is using a timeout already

@donniedarko unintuitively, the setTimeout means it's not a recursive call, it's a new call from the setTimeout's callback.

@RoryMcCrossan your code is brilliant. But, I am still a little confused as to why mine wouldn't work. In terms of single threaded operation, shouldn't JS execute what's inside case which is inside do before it would run while statement? This to me looks more asynchronous

How could I get the desired result using do while please?

document.querySelector('p').innerHTML does set the html, but, there's no time for it to update the UI.  So you never see the change.
